# Working with super in java

Tags: java, constructor, return, super

For the `Cube` class, i am trying to get rid of the error:

```
Cube.java:12: error: constructor Rectangle in class Rectangle cannot be applied to given types;
    super(x, y);
    ^
  required: int,int,double,double
  found: int,int.......
```

I know each face of a Cube is a Rectangle whose length and width need to be the same as the side of a Cube but I am not sure what needs to be passed to the Rectangle constructor to make its length and width be the same as the side of a Cube.

also trying to calculate the volume which is the area of the rectangle times the length of the Cubes sides

This is the Cube class

```
// ---------------------------------
// File Description:
//   Defines a Cube
// ---------------------------------

public class Cube extends Rectangle
{


  public Cube(int x, int y, int side)
  {
    super(x, y);
    side = super.area(); // not sure if this is right
  }


  public int    getSide()   {return side;}

  public double area()      {return 6 * super.area();}
  public double volume()    {return super.area() * side;}
  public String toString()  {return super.toString();}
}
```

and this is the rectangle class

```
// ---------------------------------
// File Description:
//   Defines a Rectangle
// ---------------------------------

public class Rectangle extends Point
{
  private int    x, y;  // Coordinates of the Point
  private double length, width;

  public Rectangle(int x, int y, double l, double w)
  {
    super(x, y);
    length = l;
    width = w;
  }

  public int       getX()         {return x;}
  public int       getY()         {return y;}
  public double    getLength()    {return length;}
  public double    getWidth()     {return width;}

  public double area()      {return length * width;}
  public String toString()  {return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]" + " Length = " + length + " Width = " + width;}
}
```

Comment: Since `Rectangle` doesn't have a constructor that takes 2 arguments, what code do you expect to be called when you invoke `super(x, y);`?

Comment: Are you sure your `Cube` needs to inherit from `Rectangle` and not simply hold an array of `Rectangles`, each with its own `Point` and length? Also, since `Rectangle` extends `Point`, you need not define `x`, `y`, `getX` or `getY` in `Rectangle` - you inherit these properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The very construction of this Object seems to miss the idea of extension.

A `Cube` is not a `Rectangle`. A `Cube` could be considered a composite of multiple `Rectangle`s with spatial data for orientation, but then the rectangles should be members (read attributes/fields) of the `Cube`.

To illustrate this point consider the difference between the following statements.

All cubes are rectangles.

All cats are animals.

you could conceivably create a `Cat` object that extends the super class `Animal`. `Cube`s and `Rectangle`s do not share this relationship.

consider refactoring your code to be something like:

```
public class Cube {
    private List<Rectangle> faces:

    ....

}
```

To take this a step further, not all `Rectangle`s are `Point`s.

A point is one pair of x, y co-ordinates. In order to accurately draw a `Rectangle` the minimum amount of information required is two `Point`s.

see

```
+--
| |
--+
```

If you have the opposite corner `Point`s (marked here by the **+**) you can draw your `Rectangle`.

In light of this, perhaps you should also refactor `Rectangle` to have a pair of `Point`s as members.

something like:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private Point firstCorner;
    private Point secondCorner;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Rectangle` constructor expects 4 arguments, and you are passing him only 2 when creating instance of `Cube`. You should pass your length also:

```
  public Cube(int x, int y, int side)
  {
    super(x, y, side, side);
  }
```

If you think a bit it makes perfect sense - any rectangle needs origin x and y, and width and height. In case of cube width and height are the same, but you should still tell the rectangle what are their values ;)

Answer (score 2):

The number of arguments in your `super(x, y)` doesn't match with the arguments in the constructor of class `Rectangle`. When you explicitly invoke super class constructor you have to make sure that the super class has a constructor that matches.

Answer (score 2):

The superclass of `Rectangle` is `Cube` not `Point`. Using `super()` you can call the constructor of `Cube` not the constructor of `Point`